# how to make tiny mce editor transparent?

Tags: tinymce

I want to make my tiny mce's editor's background transparent. I tried to edit the Ui.css and content.css for advanced themes. but no luck. I tried to add

```
allowTransparency:"allowTransparency",
```

after

```
frameBorder:"0",
```

but this also could not help. How to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is transparent by default.... What is that you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: No, it is not transparent...I want it to be transparent so that user can see the text being edited over the background image and apply styles.

Comment: So you want the entire editor to be transparent, not just its toolbar icon....?

Comment: yes..I am not using the tool bar.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

in the css. This should work in everything but IE 6.